# Laravel: How to Route to Public file

Tags: php, routes, laravel

In Laravel, **is it possible** to redirect to a `public/testFile.php`, through routing?

In the `application/routes.php`,

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    //'How to point to public/testFile.php'

});
```

*Have an existing Project, But want to do Only the NEW MODULES in Laravel. So copied the Existing project under Public/*

Comment: I haven't voted you down, but there isn't a rule requiring a user to define why they down voted. That said, this is a very basic question and also defeats the point of using an MVC framework.

Comment: I haven't voted you down, personally. Merely voiced disapproval in my answer, though in the end, whatever floats your boat. I've seen 100x worse than your question in production code, personally ;-)

Comment: So we have an existing Project, But want to do Only the NEW MODULES in Laravel. So keeping the Existing project under Public/

Comment: I figured. You do know that in this case, if you want to access the files directly, there is no need to route at all? If you don't want to, however, you can use the first of my two solutions.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien, for ur support. Let me accept ur answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are completely defeating the purpose of the framework by doing this, but if you really want to...

```
Route::get("/", function() {
    ob_start();
    require(path("public")."testFile.php");
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

This will return the stdout output of the file. If instead you have a return value already in the script, knock out `ob_start` and the `return` call.

Redirects are done as follows:

```
Route::get("/", function() { return Redirect::to("testFile.php"); });
```

Comment: And `require(path("public")."testFile.php");` can be updated to `require(public_path() . "/testFile.php");`

Comment: I have an SPA created elsewhere and I built the `SPAindex.html` through a CLI into the Laravel public folder.
I'm trying to set this up, but it's not working. How should I exactly write the controller of the route in the case I want to link `public/SPAindex.html`?

Comment: i need to get my "sitemap.xml" URL off of my project, for google search console, how would you say it's the best approach? it's stored in the public folder.

Answer (score 10):

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    include public_path().'testFile.php';
});
```

If you want to **Redirect** then use `return Redirect::to('testFile.php')`

But I don't get why you want to do this **weird** thing.

I think you are using Laravel 3 (as you mentioned `application/...`), there `public_path()` is `path('public')`.