# Laravel possible to route to a single php file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have am using Laravel and I am trying to **call a single php file via the browser**, which is

located in my app path.

I have setup a `Route::get` to a function `HomeController@index`

```
function index(){
include(app_path().'/myphpfile.php');
}
```

And gets called when doing `http://localhost:8888/home/index`

This is how I call it atm.

The Problem is my file accepts furthe parameters, which are

processed inside my php file like:

```
http://localhost:8888/myphpfile.php/user/hello1
```

or

```
http://localhost:8888/myphpfile.php/user/hello1/default
```

So I tried to use `Route::any`.

It is not working. Can I somehow just tell Laravel to pick up the php file like I mentioned above? Other way then using include?

I don´t want to put this file into the public folder.

Something like wildcard routing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean with calling a single php file? Do you mean like returning a View? I think Any won't helpe here since that is just the method GET or POST and what is the purpose of that file is it a class?

Comment: It is a SabreDAV Caldavserver.

Comment: Ehm I have no experience with that but what does the file contain? if its a class you can create a new instance of the class using new ClassName() in your model.. and then return it to your controller by a method.

Comment: No, it looks like this: https://code.google.com/p/sabredav/wiki/IntegrationGuide. I have now just dumped it in the public folder. But it says base_path() undefined...

Comment: I rather need to know if its possible to do wildcard routing

Comment: What you basically should do is put the caldav class somewhere in your libraries and use it as a class like in the example link you have posted. The other stuff u posted is irrelevant for your routing/controller since that is just a example of how to use it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46116/discussion-between-reshad-and-zer02)

Comment: Problem solved. The issue was a routing rule in htaccess

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836443/laravel-how-to-route-to-public-file#comment74996761_15837014