# Migrating PHP app to Laravel. $_SESSION data set in Laravel not available in old app php files

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm migrating an app written in PHP to Laravel. I can't move the functionality out of the PHP files yet so I have placed them in the `/public` directory and all is mostly well. The old app, however, set `$_SESSION["userId"]` when the user logged in and that is referenced in most of the files to identify the current user.

I understand Laravel's session is not the native PHP session. I've added `session_start()` to my `app.php` file and sett `$_SESSION["userId"]` when the user logs in but `$_SESSION["userId"]` in the old app files is always `undefined`.

I feel like there's a piece of the puzzle I'm still missing but I can't figure it out. I'm using a fresh Laravel 5.6 installation.

**EDIT for clarification**

The old app is comprised of many PHP files each `echo`ing JSON data which are called via ajax requests. I've simply placed them in the `public` directory and the old URLs in our Angular front end work without any changes.

The Angular app is served via `index.blade.php` in which the controller calls `session_start()` and sets the `$_SESSION["userId"]` variable before returning the view.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session

Comment: I've read through that. What about it?

Comment: You read that? Are you sure?...did you read about session put or the global helper?

Comment: Also, why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote the question btw...

Comment: Was directed at whoever did :)

Comment: The global helper is a function to access Laravel's session, not the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: And just to make things clear, based on the documentation, now you should know the way `laravel` handles `session` objects....basically now you just need to port your old `$_SESSION` to the laravel way and it should work...use the global session helper to set the session, and the `forget` and `flush` methods in order to wipe out the session when you logout from the app.

Comment: @PatrickRyan -  can you please add a bit more information (to your question) about your setup and what exactly you're trying to do. You mentioned that you dropped an existing PHP application in the `public` dir and also edited `app.php` to start a session. Are you hitting the old app directly (Ie. `public/old_app`) in the browser *and* is there some code that is bootstrapping the Lavavel application? Because if you're only hitting the old app directly, even if it is in the `public` dir, it won't magically bootstrap the Laravel application and hence, won't call your session_start().

Comment: @waterloomatt I've added some clarification.

Comment: So Laravel renders view >> view (via AJAX) calls `public/old_app`? Does `old_app` actually start a session or in anyway communicate with the base Laravel application? If not, that is the issue. As you know, I'm sure, you need to start the session on each request. Ie. When Laravel renders the view *and also* when the old_app is invoked. How you actually do the latter one is the question.

Comment: It doesn't communicate with the app. It's literally GET '/https://myapp/oldfile.php'. There's no old_app prefix or anything like that. I think I have to create a route to funnel those requests through the app.

Comment: Yip - that's the issue. You can go *through* Laravel by creating a route listener that will handle your requests. As the top answer there points out, you're totally defeating the purpose of the framework by doing this though - https://stackoverflow.com/q/15836443/296555. Not 100% sure that the session will be created by then so you might be hooped regardless. I guess you could manually start the session there but I think you'd be running into bigger issues then. My advice would be to convert your static PHP files into controller/actions ASAP and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of what I ended up implementing. It required a change in the URL to which all of the ajax requests performed.

#### web.php

```
Route::post('old/{filename}', 'OldController@post');
```

#### OldController.php

```
public function post(Request $request, $filename)
{
    if (session_id() == "") {
        session_start();
    }

    if (Auth::check()) {
        $_SESSION['userId'] = Auth::user()->userId;
    }

    $filePath = realpath(app_path() . '/../response/' . $filename);
    include $filePath; 
}
```